# My push speeds are ridiculously slow, but my pull speeds are normal

Tags: github

I am using windows, my internet connection is 40mbps d/l, 8mbps u/l. I am using the github desktop version, this is my speeds for syncing 1 file, with a full stop:

http://recordit.co/GHof0cr9k6

When I pull via bash it's maybe 1 or 2 seconds then complete, when I push either via bash or the gui it's like 15-25 seconds. When I click sync it gitters for a bit while the bar moves then the bar fills up and then hangs for 10 seconds or so as you can see in the video

I have tried pushing via bash and it's still slow. Any idea why or how to fix this?

Comment: It might be because your ISP limits uploading speed. If that is the case, you can't do anything besides switch ISPs

Answer (score 0):

The culprit seems to be your connection. It has a horribly low uploading speed (assuming that's what u/l means) which is approximately 1 MB/s.